# Database backups not writing to disc, not enough space?

Tags: linux, unix, db2, aix, system-administration

I just inherited an AIX project which I know very little about. I have a cronjob that has been failing for a few days now that does a full backup of my database(db2). Looking at the logs, I'm seeing this:

```
SQL2419N  The target disk "/home/dbtmp/backups" has become full.
```

When checking out this directory:

```
(/var/spool/cron)> df -g /home/dbtmp
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/dbtmplv      10.00      0.96   91%       85     1% /home/dbtmp
```

The size of the previous backups:

```
(/var/spool/cron)> ll /home/dbtmp/backups
total 18365248
-rw-------    1 hsprd    cics     4411498496 Feb 12 18:01 HSPRD.0.hsprd.NODE0000.CATN0000.20130212180036.001
-rw-------    1 hstrn    cics      874287104 Feb 12 18:08 HSTRN.0.hstrn.NODE0000.CATN0000.20130212180747.001
-rw-------    1 hstst    cics     3242835968 Feb 12 18:05 HSTST.0.hstst.NODE0000.CATN0000.20130212180443.001
```

What options to I have to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: what is the size of a database backup?

Comment: Borrow a disk stretcher?  (There is no way to fix it, you need a bigger disk.)

Comment: Added sizes @manu-fatto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the size of your backup files exceeds the free space on the device. You need a larger device.

Comment: According to this: http://pastebin.com/MSmHhLzE could I move the backups into another directory?

Comment: Your backup size is around 8G, your largest partition is 20G... I see a problem in you hardware configuration.

Comment: So my problem isn't necessarily disc space, but allotment?

Comment: If you want to keep nGB files you need N x number of [files to keep] bytes available.  I do this stuff for a living - we compress backup files if possible.  We also rotate older backups off disk and into the tape library.  You should develop a retention policy.